# Multiple Bootstrap tabs remaining active when generated with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following divs with special attributes that I am selecting with jQuery

```
<div data-tab-name="Description">
    <!-- content -->
</div> 
<div data-tab-name="Video">
    <!-- content -->
</div> 
<div data-tab-name="Reviews">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

I am then taking those divs and turning them into individual Bootstrap tabs (& nav-tabs) and attempting to set the first tab-pane & nav-tab to active. This is the result:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#description">Description</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#video">Video</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="row tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="description">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="video">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="reviews">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I run the code it structures it as I intended, which is what [w3school's boostrap tab example shows](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) (Dynamic Tabs), but multiple tabs are staying active when I switch between them which prevents them from being clicked twice.

What would I need to do to make it behave as it normally does when entering the html for the tabs directly? https://codepen.io/BBell/pen/RBLmEr

---

I'm not sure why stacksnippet is showing a script error, but it continues to show even if I remove the JS (http://recordit.co/8mazS35U9r). Here is a backup codepen that worked better for me:

https://codepen.io/BBell/pen/VBzJXz

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function cssEncode(name) {
        return name.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase();
    }

    var dataAttr = "data-tab-name";
    var tabDivs = $("div[" + dataAttr + "]");
    var navTabs = $('<div class="nav nav-tabs">');
    var tabContent = $('<div class="tab-content" id="tabs"></div>');
    var tabs = [];
    var tabPanes = [];
    tabDivs.each(function(e) {
        var name = $(this).attr(dataAttr);
        var encodedName = cssEncode(name);
        tabs.push(
            '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' +
            encodedName +
            '">' +
            name +
            "</a></li>"
        );
        var tabPane = $(
            '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + encodedName + '"></div>'
        ).append($(this).html());
        tabPanes.push(tabPane);
        $(this).detach();
    });
    navTabs.append(tabs.join(""));
    tabContent.append(tabPanes);
    var tabsContainer = $('<div class="tabs"></div>');
    tabsContainer.append(navTabs);
    tabsContainer.append(tabContent);
    $(".iseo-item-page .col-md-12").append(tabsContainer);
    $(".nav-tabs a:first").tab("show");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row iseo-item-page">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div data-tab-name="Description">
        Content 0
      </div>
      <div data-tab-name="Video">
        Content 1
      </div>
      <div data-tab-name="Reviews">
        Content 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that when you do it dynamically like you do the `li` elements all get class of `active` but it should be only one active. Look @ the example your provided as a working one inspect element on the tabs ... you will see that once you select a an tab/`li` it would get the `active` class and the previous one would loose it. In your example that class gets set to all so you can't again click on them.

Here is a working version with basically going around bootstrap js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function cssEncode(name) {
        return name.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase();
    }

    var dataAttr = "data-tab-name";
    var tabDivs = $("div[" + dataAttr + "]");
    var navTabs = $('<div class="nav nav-tabs">');
    var tabContent = $('<div class="tab-content" id="tabs"></div>');
    var tabs = [];
    var tabPanes = [];
    tabDivs.each(function(e) {
        var name = $(this).attr(dataAttr);
        var encodedName = cssEncode(name);
        tabs.push(
            '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' + encodedName + '">' + name + "</a></li>"
        );
        var tabPane = $(
            '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + encodedName + '"></div>'
        ).append($(this).html());
        tabPanes.push(tabPane);
        $(this).detach();
    });

    navTabs.append(tabs.join(""));
    tabContent.append(tabPanes);
    var tabsContainer = $('<div class="tabs"></div>');
    tabsContainer.append(navTabs);
    tabsContainer.append(tabContent);
    $(".iseo-item-page .col-md-12").append(tabsContainer);
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
      $('li').not(this.parentNode).removeClass('active')
   $('.iseo-item-page div').removeClass('active in')
      $(this.hash).addClass('active in')
    })  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row iseo-item-page">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div data-tab-name="Description">
        Content 0
      </div>
      <div data-tab-name="Video">
        Content 1
      </div>
      <div data-tab-name="Reviews">
        Content 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, I'm having a hard time figuring out why it's happening though. I was thinking that once my code executes on document.ready(); then it would set the first tab to active and then the default bootstrap.js code for switching tabs would take over. (Tab.prototype.show)

Comment: I looked a bit deeper and when debugging bootstrap.js on line 2126 it has the following:

    `var $active    = container.find('> .active')`

When looking at the html example $active has a value of

    `$active = jQuery.fn.init [li.active, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]`

and the jQuery example has the value:

    `$active = jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(0)]`

For some reason, container.find isn't finding any of the nav-tabs I've generated

Comment: I updated my previous answer with a working version. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I tweaked it a bit and it's working perfect. (The first tab wasn't displayed by default)

Comment: Awesome. Glad I was able to help. If it solved your problem mark the answer as  final (accept it). Thanks :)